# displaying files and DIRECTORIES via php?

Tags: php

i have a propably rather simple question:
I'm using the following script to read a folder?

```
    $count = 0;
if ($handle = opendir(PATH)) {
    $retval = array();
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.DS_Store' && $file != 'Thumbs.db') {
            $retval[$count] = $file;
            $count = $count + 1;
        } else {
            //no proper file
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

if a file is an image I print it as an image: print "";

However i wonder how i can display FOLDERS? If i have a subfolder inside of the folder i'm currently running through? how can i print that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `scandir` instead of `readdir`.  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: any chance you can show me how i can transform my code above to work with scandir? in my case i'm always looking for the file-extension. so if $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); equals e.g. jpg or gif i'm printing out an image. how can i print out a folder?

Comment: Use `is_dir` to determine if the path is a directory.  The only change your code needs to work with `scandir` is to call `scandir` once and then loop over its output, instead of calling `readdir` repeatedly.  Unless you want recursion, in which case you'll have to implement that by changing your code a wee bit more.

Answer (score 1):

use [glob](http://php.net/glob) instead of scandir

```
$dirs = glob(PATH."/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$images = glob(PATH."/*.[jJ][pJ][gG]");

foreach ($dirs as $name) echo "<b>$name</b><br>\n";
foreach ($images as $name) echo $name."<br>\n";
```

Comment: @Borealid because glob is 10 times shorter